# Show/Hide items in itemscontrol on condition

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, itemscontrol

I have an Itemscontrol that I am using to display a list of start information sent from a timing system.

I need to be able to "switch off"/stop displaying a set of lane info if the lane number isn't showing (if it's null or a blank) and then if the timer sends info to switch the lane back on then show the data again.

I can't set it to just delete everything because the timer sends its information constantly and everything except the lane number would reappear again.

Is it possible to show/hide items on condition?

What is currently happening

```
Lanes
1 ------
2 ------
  ------ <- other info remains
4 ------
```

What I want to happen

```
Lanes
1 ------
2 ------

4 ------
```

Here is a sample of my itemscontrol code

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CHeat.SwimList}" Margin="10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Content="Lane" />
                            <Label Content="Pos" />
                            <Label Content="Swimmer" />
                            <Label Content="Club" />
                            <Label Content="Time" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding LaneNumber}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Position}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Swimmer}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding Club}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="4" Content="{Binding Time}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

If there was a way I could set `Content = ""` for the other data based off the LaneNumber then I believe it could work, because then I can just bring back the bindings.

I'm fairly new to WPF so extra detail would be helpful many thanks!

Comment: `Is it possible to show/hide items on condition?` -> Yes it's called `Triggers` has multiple types. For your case, you could be using a `DataTrigger` to check if the Lane number is null/empty and if so set the `Visibility` of that item to `Hidden`. just google to see examples for `DataTrigger`. Also if your new to WPF, `Label` has a specific purpose in WPF. It does a whole load more than just display "text", if you're just after showing text, use a `TextBlock`. Also check some example's for WPF Layout's. What you're doing isn't "wrong" but could be done better.

Comment: @Viv Thanks I'll see what I can come up with that should work. In what way do you think I could improve the layout? It is a WIP so it looks a bit all over the place at the moment but I was more concerned about it being functional.

Comment: You're welcome. As for the layout, say things like in the `DataTemplate` why nest a `Grid` inside a `StackPanel` when it's the only child. Also Fixed Width's in WPF is frowned upon **unless** essential. In your case you got the column size's fixed and thus it ain't scalable. You could use "*" based multipliers to allocate space for Grid control's based on a percentage of what's available. If you just need fixed dimension, you might as well specify the Width on the item's and get rid of the `Grid`. You ain't going to get it all in a day, If you're tryin that's good enough. Just keep refining.

Comment: Oh right!! The reason the fixed width is there is basically quick and dirty so that I can see that things display I'll be changing that before long because it has to resize for fullscreen use etc. As the stackpanel and grid I originally had only the stackpanel to just put everything in a horizontal line and I've forgotten to remove it! Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try using the `Visibility` property?
you just have to create a public property in your MVVM or code behind and the Bind it to the element you want to hide.

```
 <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding ShowElement, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

By setting the boolean value of ShowElement, you can easily hide or show the StackPanel.